# Cannot access "Current user" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise and devise_ldap for my rails authentication. I am trying to use the built in helper, current user to display the users email on the welcome page of my application.
This is the code that I have tried to use to:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
 <div>Signed in as... <%= current_user.email %></div>
<% end %>
```

when I sign in to the application, I get the error;

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 devise_for :users
 resources :users
 resources :systems do
  member do
   get :targets, :sources
 end
 root      'systems#index'
end
```

and my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
authorize_resource
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /users
def index
@users = User.all.order("display_name asc")
end

# GET /users/1
def show
end

# GET /users/new
def new
    @user = User.new
end

# GET /stories/1/edit
def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
end

# POST /stories
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
       puts 'user controller'
      if @user.save!
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
end

# PATCH/PUT /stories/1
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
end

# DELETE /stories/1
def destroy
@user.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_path notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end



# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:display_name, :email, :username)
end
end
```

my users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
before_create :rememberable_value

before_save :get_ldap_values

devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

def get_ldap_values
  if self.username
    self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail").first if Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail")
    self.display_name = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"displayName").first if Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"displayName")
  end
end

# def role?(role)
#     return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
# end

def email_required?
    false
end

def email_changed?
    false
end
def rememberable_value
    self.remember_token ||= Devise.friendly_token
end

def name_to_display
    if self.display_name
        self.display_name
    else
        self.username
    end
end

def password_required?
    false
end

def password_match?
    self.errors[:password] << "can't be blank" if password.blank?
    self.errors[:password_confirmation] << "can't be blank" if password_confirmation.blank?
    self.errors[:password_confirmation] << "does not match password" if password != password_confirmation
    password == password_confirmation && !password.blank?
end
end
```

I am not sure what I am missing to be able to access the current users information after a successful sign in.

**Update**

Here is the new routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


devise_scope :user do
 get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
 get "/users/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new"
 # delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end

devise_for :users
authenticate(:user) do
 resources :users
 resources :reports
 resources :change_logs, only: [:index, :show]
 resources :systems do
  member do
    get :targets, :sources
  end
  resources :change_logs, module: :systems
  resources :components do
    resources :change_logs, module: :components
  end
  resources :c_relations
 end

 resources :integrations
  get '/static_pages/home'  # => 'static_pages#home', as: 'home'
 root      'systems#index'
end
```

Comment: is the `user_signed_in?` a devise method or did you write it? If it's the former can you provide its body?

Comment: it is a devise method;  To verify if a user is signed in, use the following helper: user_signed_in?

Comment: From the devise source code, it seems that the user_signed_in? method is dynamically defined as `{mapping}_signed_in?`. Have you by any chance overriden (is that a word?) the `devise_mapping` option in your application_helper?  (...or @Matt 's answer)

Comment: does the log show that you are hitting the database and LDAP?, e.g Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-16 09:10:27 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {...}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2605ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-16 09:10:30 +0100
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1

Comment: yes the log shows that I am hitting the database and LDAP. I just cannot access current_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had overridden the devise mapping and current_user. I removed them and was able to access current user in my views.

Answer (score 2):

In routes.rb you should enclose the rows following

```
devise_for :users
```

in a block

```
authenticate(:user) do
  resources :users
  [...]
end
```

Comment: should all my resources go in that block or just users?

Comment: All those for which you want to authenticate the user. No authentication, no current_user around.

Comment: see my update for the routes file. I am still getting the error; `undefined method email for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `before_action :authenticate_user!` [in your controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) chain at all?

Current_user could be nil after signin is if you aren't asking devise to authenticate the action.

Comment: I have it in my applications controller